# ios autolayout autoresizing does not work

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have just created one button centred it horizontally and vertically and fixed its height.

When I run the program in emulator and compare heights for iphone 6+ and iphone 6, the height of button is remarkably smaller for 6 than for 6+. That's okay.

However in 4s emulator, the height of button is the same as the height in iphone 6 one. Can someone explain why this happens? the height of screen for 4s is smaller than for 6, but the height of button remains the same.

This fact causes a lot of problems for me to build a nice user interface to be compatible for all iphone devices. I have always this kind of problem that I need an object e.g button to be small in 4s. When I make it smaller, then it is too small for 6 or 6 plus

Thank you

Comment: u need to give at least 4 constraint

Comment: Is it the height of the button that is changing or the coordinate of the button?

Comment: I know about constraints. I did. The question is about resizing

Comment: Coordinates are okay. it is centred vertically and horizontally.  Position does not matter, wherever I place it, the size is problem. The height seems too big for me for 4s iphone

Comment: 4s and 6 have the same dpi, so the height is also equal to

Comment: @LDNZh then how I should build a UI for both? I've built now an UI that fits perfectly for iphone 6, but in 4s it looks ugly because the height of screen is not enough...

Comment: You may create outlet for height constraint and in code change the value of height for 4s.

Comment: Yes it's a solution but I'm not sure that it's the right one

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed height constraint the button will have the same height on all devices. What you could do is make an `IBOutlet` for your height constraint and change it in code to the desired size for each screen size.

```
@interface MyResizingButton ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;

@end

@implementation IMScrollViewFillingView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [self.heightConstraint setConstant:0.3*CGRectGetHeight(self.superview.frame)];
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

The code above will make your button smaller or bigger depending on the size of the `superview`. I assumed the button is added to a view that resizes depending on the device screen size (like the root view in a `UIViewController`). You might need to adjust the calculation to fit your design.

As you can see, I created a custom `UIButton` class to handle this adjustable height. For it to work, you will need to set the class of the `UIButton` in the `storyboard` to this custom class. Of course, you can add the code directly in your view controller, then you would not need the custom button class.

Another option would be to not use a fixed height, but connect the height of the button to something else, using the `aspect ratio` constraints. Since I don't really know how your interface works, I can't really give you a concrete example for this case.

Hope this helps fix your problem.